# Why the method with `int` parameter is called when I pass `char` type?

Tags: java, string

is it possible to  pass char type variable in the method which accept only `String` type? To understand my question regarding this Please clarify how it is possible when call
`calculation(ch)` method from `main()`?

```
public class OverLoadingTestString {

    static void calculation(String str){
        System.out.println("String");
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char ch='r';
        calculation(ch);
    }
}
```

Comment: char can be promoted to int. So "int" was printed,

Comment: It is accepting char without type casting without error.So my doubt?

Comment: @RahulTripathi I suggest you to change your title since answers are misunderstanding your question. See my answer, hopefully it does help you.

Comment: Why did you delete one of your `calculation()` methods? Your question title makes no sense anymore.

Answer (score 4):

*No* but you can convert it to `String` as both are incompatible so try like this,

```
calculation(String.valueOf(ch));
```

And yes you even *don't need to convert if* you want to pass `ASCII` value of Character to the method `calculation(int a)` which accepts `int` than `calculation('A')` is valid.

Comment: No need to type cast.it is accepting directly char in argument

Comment: @RahulTripathi: There is no type cast in this answer. Your question is *"is it possible to pass char type variable in the method which accept only String type in java?"* This answers that question.

Answer (score 3):

The [*most accurate* method will be called - See JLS **Determine Method Signature**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2). In your case, you have two methods that have different signatures, one accepts `String`, one accepts `int`.

When you call:

```
calculation(ch);
```

Since `ch` is `char`, it cannot be applied to the method accepting `String` because `char` won't be *implicitly* converted to `String`. However, it can be called to the method that accepts `int` and the ASCII value of it will be transferred.

Answer (score 0):

No, **But** you can use [String.valueOf()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf%28char%29)

```
char ch='r';
calculation(String.valueOf(ch));
```

Or you can just use as follows too.

```
char ch='r';
calculation(""+ch);
```

Comment: @RahulTripathi what? There is no casting here.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you want to know how the overload works.. Please refer this [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) API and read about the valueOf methods. Those methods are overloaded methods.

Hope this will help you...

Answer (score 0):

The 1st "calculation" method takes string as argument where the 2nd one takes integer.
When you are passing character 'r', the second calculation method is called as ASCII value of 'r' is passed to the method. That is why it is compiling.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible to auto type cast from char to String .This code will not compile.

So solving solution do the steps

char ch='r';
calculation(String.valueOf(ch));